# Package mapbox_gl flutter raised exception

Tags: android, flutter, dictionary, mapbox, mapbox-gl

How can I solve the "java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError" exception when using Mapbox GL in a Flutter application on Android?

I'm developing a Flutter application that uses the Mapbox GL plugin to display a map with markers and a user's location. The app works fine on iOS devices, but on Android I'm getting the following exception:

The exception I got :

```
An Observatory debugger and profiler on Redmi Note 9S is available at: http://127.0.0.1:49528/Xy5jpgdNaII=/
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on Redmi Note 9S is available at:
http://127.0.0.1:9100?uri=http://127.0.0.1:49528/Xy5jpgdNaII=/
W/CrashReporter(21195): Root directory doesn't exist
I/TetheringManager(21195): registerTetheringEventCallback:com.touchpoint.touchpoint
W/TelemetryUtils(21195): java.lang.SecurityException: getDataNetworkTypeForSubscriber
V/Mbgl-ConnectivityReceiver(21195): connected - true
E/FrameEvents(21195): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/LocationCollectionCli(21195): java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient, but class was expected (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient' appears in /data/app/~~3kk7pimqwcWCXcVltEeH4w==/com.touchpoint.touchpoint-xYSpb4RB7ZdKTrBA3mYV4w==/base.apk)
D/SurfaceView(21195): UPDATE null, mIsCastMode = false
I/Mbgl-EGLConfigChooser(21195): In emulator: false
W/Mbgl    (21195): {GLThread 297573}[Android]: MapRenderer::onSurfaceCreated GlyphsRasterizationMode was specified without providing LocalIdeographFontFamily. Switching glyphsRasterizationMode to NoGlyphsRasterizedLocally mode.
E/FrameEvents(21195): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
I/Mbgl    (21195): {GLThread 297573}[General]: GPU Identifier: Adreno (TM) 618
E/FrameEvents(21195): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(21195): Exception in onDidFinishLoadingStyle
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(21195): java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient, but class was expected (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient' appears in /data/app/~~3kk7pimqwcWCXcVltEeH4w==/com.touchpoint.touchpoint-xYSpb4RB7ZdKTrBA3mYV4w==/base.apk)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(21195):        at com.mapbox.android.core.location.GoogleLocationEngineImpl.requestLocationUpdates(GoogleLocationEngineImpl.java:58)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(21195):        at com.mapbox.android.core.location.GoogleLocationEngineImpl.requestLocationUpdates(GoogleLocationEngineImpl.java:26)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(21195):        at com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineProxy.requestLocationUpdates(LocationEngineProxy.java:34)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(21195):        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.LocationComponent.onLocationLayerStart(LocationComponent.java:1439)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(21195):        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.LocationComponent.enableLocationComponent(LocationComponent.java:1568)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(21195):        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.LocationComponent.setLocationComponentEnabled(LocationComponent.java:551)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(21195):        at com.mapbox.mapboxgl.MapboxMapController.enableLocationComponent(MapboxMapController.java:274)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(21195):        at com.mapbox.mapboxgl.MapboxMapController.updateMyLocationEnabled(MapboxMapController.java:1563)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(21195):        at com.mapbox.mapboxgl.MapboxMapController.access$100(MapboxMapController.java:91)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(21195):        at com.mapbox.mapboxgl.MapboxMapController$1.onStyleLoaded(MapboxMapController.java:141)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(21195):        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap.notifyStyleLoaded(MapboxMap.java:963)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(21195):        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap.onFinishLoadingStyle(MapboxMap.java:225)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(21195):        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView$MapCallback.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(MapView.java:1383)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(21195):        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapChangeReceiver.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(MapChangeReceiver.java:198)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(21195):        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.NativeMapView.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(NativeMapView.java:1166)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(21195):        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(21195):        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(21195):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(21195):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7861)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(21195):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(21195):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:600)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(21195):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
W/System.err(21195): java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient, but class was expected (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient' appears in /data/app/~~3kk7pimqwcWCXcVltEeH4w==/com.touchpoint.touchpoint-xYSpb4RB7ZdKTrBA3mYV4w==/base.apk)
W/System.err(21195):    at com.mapbox.android.core.location.GoogleLocationEngineImpl.requestLocationUpdates(GoogleLocationEngineImpl.java:58)
W/System.err(21195):    at com.mapbox.android.core.location.GoogleLocationEngineImpl.requestLocationUpdates(GoogleLocationEngineImpl.java:26)
W/System.err(21195):    at com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineProxy.requestLocationUpdates(LocationEngineProxy.java:34)
W/System.err(21195):    at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.LocationComponent.onLocationLayerStart(LocationComponent.java:1439)
W/System.err(21195):    at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.LocationComponent.enableLocationComponent(LocationComponent.java:1568)
W/System.err(21195):    at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.LocationComponent.setLocationComponentEnabled(LocationComponent.java:551)
W/System.err(21195):    at com.mapbox.mapboxgl.MapboxMapController.enableLocationComponent(MapboxMapController.java:274)
W/System.err(21195):    at com.mapbox.mapboxgl.MapboxMapController.updateMyLocationEnabled(MapboxMapController.java:1563)
W/System.err(21195):    at com.mapbox.mapboxgl.MapboxMapController.access$100(MapboxMapController.java:91)
W/System.err(21195):    at com.mapbox.mapboxgl.MapboxMapController$1.onStyleLoaded(MapboxMapController.java:141)
W/System.err(21195):    at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap.notifyStyleLoaded(MapboxMap.java:963)
W/System.err(21195):    at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap.onFinishLoadingStyle(MapboxMap.java:225)
W/System.err(21195):    at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView$MapCallback.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(MapView.java:1383)
W/System.err(21195):    at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapChangeReceiver.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(MapChangeReceiver.java:198)
W/System.err(21195):    at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.NativeMapView.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(NativeMapView.java:1166)
W/System.err(21195):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
W/System.err(21195):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
W/System.err(21195):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
W/System.err(21195):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7861)
W/System.err(21195):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err(21195):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:600)
W/System.err(21195):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
E/libc++abi(21195): terminating with uncaught exception of type jni::PendingJavaException
F/libc    (21195): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 21195 (oint.touchpoint), pid 21195 (oint.touchpoint)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'Redmi/curtana_global/curtana:11/RKQ1.200826.002/V12.5.5.0.RJWMIXM:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2023-03-28 22:11:25+0800
pid: 21195, tid: 21195, name: oint.touchpoint  >>> com.touchpoint.touchpoint <<<
uid: 12114
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'terminating with uncaught exception of type jni::PendingJavaException'
    x0  0000000000000000  x1  00000000000052cb  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000007fe96bd3a0
    x4  fefeff6d6e68736f  x5  fefeff6d6e68736f  x6  fefeff6d6e68736f  x7  7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
    x8  00000000000000f0  x9  4137f4ed66572a41  x10 0000000000000000  x11 ffffffc0fffffbdf
    x12 0000000000000001  x13 656378456176614a  x14 0000007789788be2  x15 00000000000001d6
    x16 0000007789784948  x17 00000077897633d0  x18 000000778e858000  x19 00000000000052cb
    x20 00000000000052cb  x21 00000000ffffffff  x22 ffffff80ffffffc8  x23 0000007fe96bd5f0
    x24 0000007fe96bd4d0  x25 0000007fe96bd510  x26 0000007670327968  x27 0000007670327960
    x28 0000007670327980  x29 0000007fe96bd420
    lr  0000007789716ae0  sp  0000007fe96bd380  pc  0000007789716b0c  pst 0000000000001000
backtrace:
      #00 pc 0000000000089b0c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+164) (BuildId: 2e8a650ddf4a10855ff9ad91c011753e)
      #01 pc 0000000000373aa4  /data/app/~~3kk7pimqwcWCXcVltEeH4w==/com.touchpoint.touchpoint-xYSpb4RB7ZdKTrBA3mYV4w==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #02 pc 0000000000373c14  /data/app/~~3kk7pimqwcWCXcVltEeH4w==/com.touchpoint.touchpoint-xYSpb4RB7ZdKTrBA3mYV4w==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #03 pc 00000000003711d4  /data/app/~~3kk7pimqwcWCXcVltEeH4w==/com.touchpoint.touchpoint-xYSpb4RB7ZdKTrBA3mYV4w==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #04 pc 0000000000370800  /data/app/~~3kk7pimqwcWCXcVltEeH4w==/com.touchpoint.touchpoint-xYSpb4RB7ZdKTrBA3mYV4w==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #05 pc 000000000037075c  /data/app/~~3kk7pimqwcWCXcVltEeH4w==/com.touchpoint.touchpoint-xYSpb4RB7ZdKTrBA3mYV4w==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (__cxa_throw+112) (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #06 pc 0000000000094680  /data/app/~~3kk7pimqwcWCXcVltEeH4w==/com.touchpoint.touchpoint-xYSpb4RB7ZdKTrBA3mYV4w==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #07 pc 00000000000aee88  /data/app/~~3kk7pimqwcWCXcVltEeH4w==/com.touchpoint.touchpoint-xYSpb4RB7ZdKTrBA3mYV4w==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #08 pc 0000000000115b8c  /data/app/~~3kk7pimqwcWCXcVltEeH4w==/com.touchpoint.touchpoint-xYSpb4RB7ZdKTrBA3mYV4w==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #09 pc 00000000001c3898  /data/app/~~3kk7pimqwcWCXcVltEeH4w==/com.touchpoint.touchpoint-xYSpb4RB7ZdKTrBA3mYV4w==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #10 pc 00000000001c3314  /data/app/~~3kk7pimqwcWCXcVltEeH4w==/com.touchpoint.touchpoint-xYSpb4RB7ZdKTrBA3mYV4w==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #11 pc 00000000001c5b70  /data/app/~~3kk7pimqwcWCXcVltEeH4w==/com.touchpoint.touchpoint-xYSpb4RB7ZdKTrBA3mYV4w==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #12 pc 000000000022177c  /data/app/~~3kk7pimqwcWCXcVltEeH4w==/com.touchpoint.touchpoint-xYSpb4RB7ZdKTrBA3mYV4w==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #13 pc 00000000000fb3e0  /data/app/~~3kk7pimqwcWCXcVltEeH4w==/com.touchpoint.touchpoint-xYSpb4RB7ZdKTrBA3mYV4w==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #14 pc 000000000021b0c4  /data/app/~~3kk7pimqwcWCXcVltEeH4w==/com.touchpoint.touchpoint-xYSpb4RB7ZdKTrBA3mYV4w==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #15 pc 000000000021a930  /data/app/~~3kk7pimqwcWCXcVltEeH4w==/com.touchpoint.touchpoint-xYSpb4RB7ZdKTrBA3mYV4w==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #16 pc 000000000021a9fc  /data/app/~~3kk7pimqwcWCXcVltEeH4w==/com.touchpoint.touchpoint-xYSpb4RB7ZdKTrBA3mYV4w==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #17 pc 0000000000219c24  /data/app/~~3kk7pimqwcWCXcVltEeH4w==/com.touchpoint.touchpoint-xYSpb4RB7ZdKTrBA3mYV4w==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #18 pc 0000000000019da8  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+916) (BuildId: 4e69b93bf70ed592f0029dbd1097529e)
      #19 pc 00000000000199ac  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+112) (BuildId: 4e69b93bf70ed592f0029dbd1097529e)
      #20 pc 0000000000118278  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long, int)+44) (BuildId: 92c9cd4976d158ff290ed172a211c180)
      #21 pc 000000000021badc  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (art_jni_trampoline+140) (BuildId: cdfdaaeb5b66a45a672937e97690c44a49dfcee3)
      #22 pc 00000000020028f4  /memfd:jit-cache (deleted) (offset 0x2000000) (android.os.MessageQueue.next+180)
      #23 pc 0000000000133564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #24 pc 00000000001a8a78  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #25 pc 0000000000319380  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+376) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #26 pc 000000000030f6ac  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+996) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #27 pc 000000000067d388  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+848) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #28 pc 000000000012d814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #29 pc 00000000003c0c62  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x929000) (android.os.Looper.loop+154)
      #30 pc 0000000000306ca8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.829997668608136289)+268) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #31 pc 000000000030ec98  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+200) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #32 pc 0000000000310080  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, true>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1772) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #33 pc 0000000000177f40  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<true, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+57848) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #34 pc 000000000013f7d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #35 pc 00000000001a6f64  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread.main)
      #36 pc 0000000000306db0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.829997668608136289)+532) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #37 pc 000000000066c090  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+780) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #38 pc 000000000013cff8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #39 pc 00000000001337e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #40 pc 00000000001a8a94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+228) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #41 pc 000000000055658c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned long)+1364) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #42 pc 00000000004d5ea0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+52) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #43 pc 00000000000896f4  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+180) (BuildId: 96a2ad2581099975b8c7bb4ab40fb39a7086a166)
      #44 pc 0000000000133564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #45 pc 00000000001a8a78  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #46 pc 0000000000319380  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+376) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #47 pc 000000000030f6ac  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+996) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #48 pc 000000000067d388  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+848) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #49 pc 000000000012d814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #50 pc 00000000005001ce  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x1227000) (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+22)
      #51 pc 0000000000306ca8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.829997668608136289)+268) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #52 pc 000000000066c090  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+780) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #53 pc 000000000013cff8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #54 pc 000000000088dc4c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+2316) (BuildId: cdfdaaeb5b66a45a672937e97690c44a49dfcee3)
      #55 pc 00000000001337e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #56 pc 00000000001a8a94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+228) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #57 pc 0000000000554fc8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, std::__va_list)+448) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #58 pc 000000000055547c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<_jmethodID*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+92) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #59 pc 0000000000439c84  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<true>::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+656) (BuildId: 6fae6ac805b21c2eb5f0f1ffa98cd3db)
      #60 pc 000000000009d424  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+124) (BuildId: 92c9cd4976d158ff290ed172a211c180)
      #61 pc 00000000000a5364  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+916) (BuildId: 92c9cd4976d158ff290ed172a211c180)
      #62 pc 0000000000003680  /system/bin/app_process64 (main+1592) (BuildId: 1ffa62ce1e071ff696118eca58ad6849)
      #63 pc 00000000000850e4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+108) (BuildId: 2e8a650ddf4a10855ff9ad91c011753e)
Lost connection to device.
```

From a google search, I found that I have to add this line into `build.gradle` and added MapBoxCredential in `gradle.properties` which I did:

```
ndk {
     abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86_64', 'x86'
 }
```

I have tried various solutions including cleaning and rebuilding the project, updating the dependencies, and checking the version compatibility of the dependencies, but nothing seems to work.

What could be causing this issue and how can I fix it? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just faced the same error. According to the release notes of the google play services, there is a breaking change: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#october_13_2022.

Add the following lines to your android/build.gradle file. This overrides the location services dependency used by the android mapbox sdk.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        // This is new!
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:20.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should only be necessary until mapbox_gl depends on the newer version of the android mabpox sdk ([10.10.0](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-android/issues/1752#issuecomment-1354535597)). Hope it helps :)